# Autocomplete in Phonegap for Android

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have an autocomplete field in an app I developed using HTML5 and Phonegap Build.

When I select a value in the autocomplete field it opens the browser's autocomplete list automaticlly.

I want to prevent it.

I tried `autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your page tag

```
data-dom-cache="false"
```